# convert list of list of float into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is a pretty basic question but I cannot get the answer. I have a list `l = [[1500.0]]` and I wish to convert it into `l = [1500.0]` but I am unable to do so.
I've tried:

```
[float(x) for [x] in elements_in_l]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you already have floats inside your list in your list, `[x[0] for x in l]` should be enough

Comment: `l = l[0]`? Or could there be more than one element?

Comment: There could be more than one element @TimPietzcker

Comment: Please show an example.

Comment: This gives me an error ```TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable ``` @MatsLindh

Comment: @M_Arora In that case you don't have the list you've included in your example. `l = [[1500.0]]`, `[x[0] for x in l]` => `[1500.0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```